# Stockfish Engine breaks when loaded from a view controller instead of the app delegate iOS

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, chess

I trying to implement the Stockfish UCI engine into a chess game app. Originally in the Stockfish iOS game the view controller that holds the board and the pieces is loaded from the app delegate. What I am trying to do is have a few more screens before navigating to the game. The problem I have is that the as soon as I load the board screen the game breaks in **bitboard.cpp** file with the message **EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x1fa80000)** and a few times I have managed to load the pieces on the board and move one of them but then it brakes in the same place shown below on this line: **occupancy[size] = b;**

```
void init_magics(Bitboard table[], Bitboard* attacks[], Bitboard magics[],
               Bitboard masks[], unsigned shifts[], Square deltas[], Fn index) {

int MagicBoosters[][8] = { {  969, 1976, 2850,  542, 2069, 2852, 1708,  164 },
                           { 3101,  552, 3555,  926,  834,   26, 2131, 1117 } };

RKISS rk;
Bitboard occupancy[4096], reference[4096], edges, b;
int i, size, booster;

// attacks[s] is a pointer to the beginning of the attacks table for square 's'
attacks[SQ_A1] = table;

for (Square s = SQ_A1; s <= SQ_H8; ++s)
{
    // Board edges are not considered in the relevant occupancies
    edges = ((Rank1BB | Rank8BB) & ~rank_bb(s)) | ((FileABB | FileHBB) & ~file_bb(s));

    // Given a square 's', the mask is the bitboard of sliding attacks from
    // 's' computed on an empty board. The index must be big enough to contain
    // all the attacks for each possible subset of the mask and so is 2 power
    // the number of 1s of the mask. Hence we deduce the size of the shift to
    // apply to the 64 or 32 bits word to get the index.
    masks[s]  = sliding_attack(deltas, s, 0) & ~edges;
    shifts[s] = (Is64Bit ? 64 : 32) - popcount<Max15>(masks[s]);

    // Use Carry-Rippler trick to enumerate all subsets of masks[s] and
    // store the corresponding sliding attack bitboard in reference[].
    b = size = 0;
    do {

        occupancy[size] = b;
        reference[size] = sliding_attack(deltas, s, b);

        if (HasPext)
            attacks[s][_pext_u64(b, masks[s])] = reference[size];

        size++;
        b = (b - masks[s]) & masks[s];
    } while (b);

    // Set the offset for the table of the next square. We have individual
    // table sizes for each square with "Fancy Magic Bitboards".
    if (s < SQ_H8)
        attacks[s + 1] = attacks[s] + size;

    if (HasPext)
        continue;

    booster = MagicBoosters[Is64Bit][rank_of(s)];

    // Find a magic for square 's' picking up an (almost) random number
    // until we find the one that passes the verification test.
    do {
        do magics[s] = rk.magic_rand<Bitboard>(booster);
        while (popcount<Max15>((magics[s] * masks[s]) >> 56) < 6);

        std::memset(attacks[s], 0, size * sizeof(Bitboard));

        // A good magic must map every possible occupancy to an index that
        // looks up the correct sliding attack in the attacks[s] database.
        // Note that we build up the database for square 's' as a side
        // effect of verifying the magic.
        for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            Bitboard& attack = attacks[s][index(s, occupancy[i])];

            if (attack && attack != reference[i])
                break;

            assert(reference[i]);

            attack = reference[i];
        }
    } while (i < size);
}
```

I have not much experience and knowledge in C++ and I am struggling to figure out what is causing the issue.

Comment: "breaks"?  What is it's problem?

Comment: I have edited the issue to show the problem

Comment: I doubt anyone can help.  Stockfish is certainly not inherently broken (double-check that the version you have is considered bug-free), so I would hazard a guess that the issue relates to initialisation.  The normal version is a self-contained executable, however if you are embedding it into an iOS app then you will have had to mess with it's initialisation code.

Comment: I used the same way to initialise it as they use in the stockfish iOS app just not in the app delegate but the game seems to be very tricky to start. I have downloaded the source code which is on their website so it should be the latest version, and the actual stockfish game works when started from this download.

Comment: Thanks to trojanfoe I have dug deep and found that the problem was initialisation! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to sort it out now! I figured that the game was still initialising while I was loading its view and this caused the whole issue, because the initialiser was running in the background! To sort it out I have made a loading screen and called the initialisers for the game there! And once it is all set up in the background I load the screen with the game!!! Hope my post helps someone in the future!

Comment: also XCode suggests that the use of `abs` values has no effect in the C++ code of the game but if you remove them the code breaks.